# r'\U' gives SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'rawunicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm in Python 2.7.

```
test = r'\U'
```

gives:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'rawunicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX
```

I thought raw strings were supposed to ignore backslashes. No?

I want a string that actually contains '\' and 'U'.

In case it matters, I'm also using:

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals)
```

Comment: `from __future__ import unicode_literals` is the cause.

Comment: @StephenRauch Ah. Why?

Comment: If I knew that I would have answered instead of upvoting.  Hopefully someone who knows these things will wander by and enlighten us.

Comment: Weird. This problem disappears when I remove the `unicode_literals` import. And of course, I can do this in Python 3 no problems.

Comment: So, yet *another* reason to just use Python 3 ;)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't consider this a duplicate. That other question doesn't address the raw string issue. (The answer does, but not the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 2 raw unicode strings have a [bizarre quirk](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) where they still process `\u` and `\U` sequences:

> When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is used in conjunction with a 'u' or 'U' prefix, then the \uXXXX and \UXXXXXXXX escape sequences are processed while all other backslashes are left in the string.

The docs describe the behavior of combining the `r` and `u` prefixes, but I believe this also applies to combining the `r` prefix and `unicode_literals`.